# PHP $_SESSION variable undefined using Slim

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to set a session variable in php using Slim. I want the users id to be stored as a variable to use elsewhere. I think I have the syntax or order wrong in my functions.

Here is my function to set the variable:

```php
function loadAdmin()
{
    //Set new session and save user id to variable
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }

    $app          = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    $token        = $app->request->headers->get('token');
    $token_exists = getToken_Validate();

    if($token_exists) {
        $sql = "SELECT id, title AS admin_title, last_name AS admin_last_name
                FROM admin WHERE token=:token";
        try {
            $db   = getDB();
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

            $stmt->bindValue(':token', $token);
            $stmt->execute();

            $admin = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $db    = null;

            echo json_encode($admin); 

            $_SESSION['uid'] = $stmt['id'];          
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
        }
    } else {
        echo '{"err": "failed"}';
    }
}
```

Here is my function to use the variable when fetching specific data:

```php
function loadDashboard() 
{
    session_start();    
    $uid = $_SESSION['uid'];

    $token_exists = getToken_Validate();

    if ($token_exists) {
        //Get number of rows from multiple tables
        $sql = "SELECT 
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE id=:uid) AS total_students,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM subjects) AS total_subjects,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM notes) AS total_notes";

        try {
            $db = getDB();
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindValue(':uid', $uid);
            $stmt->execute();
            $users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $db = null;

            echo json_encode($users);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
        }
    } else {
        echo '{"err": "failed"}';
    }
}
```

The Slim error I get after trying to loadDashboard is:

> Undefined index: uid

Sorry if my PHP is awful, any help is appreciated.

Comment: So it tells me that uid has not been set yet. You need to check if it is exists or not before assigning it to a variable (before using it). If not exists then you need to run the procedure to set it first.

Comment: Have you tried to inspect your `$_SESSION` with a `var_dump()`? You may also consider adopting [Slim's session/cookie management](http://docs.slimframework.com/sessions/cookies/)

Comment: What version of Slim are you using ? Looks like 2.x by the ::getInstance()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it had nothing to do with Slim.

$_SESSION['uid'] = $stmt['id']; was not storing anything to the variable.

I had to first bind the id column to a variable:

```
$stmt->bindColumn('id', $uid);
```

Then I could set that variable as a session variable:

```
$_SESSION['uid'] = $uid;
```

Here is the full working function:

```
function loadAdmin() 
{
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }

    $app            = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    $token          = $app->request->headers->get('token');
    $token_exists   = getToken_Validate();

    if($token_exists) {
        $sql = "SELECT 
        id,
        title AS admin_title, 
        last_name AS admin_last_name 
        FROM admin WHERE token=:token";
        try {
            $db     = getDB();
            $stmt   = $db->prepare($sql);

            $stmt->bindValue(':token', $token);
            $stmt->execute();

            $stmt->bindColumn('id', $uid);

            $admin  = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $db     = null;

            $_SESSION['uid'] = $uid;            

            echo json_encode($admin);
        }

        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
        }

    }

    else {
      echo '{"err": "failed"}';
    }
}
```